# Omnifaces validateBean: can not get showMessageFor attirbute to work

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, omnifaces

I am using [Omnifaces `<o:validateBean />`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean) to use JSR303 bean validation with a class level constraint. My question is based on a former question about [how to attach message to specific components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35982491/5176800). Since Omnifaces 2.6 there is a `showMessageFor` attribute which solves my question at that time completely (so big thanks to the developers of Omnifaces library ;-). My problem is that I can not get it to work.

Here is my setting. I have three input fields, two of them are coupled in a class level constraint (weddingDay must be smaller than silverWeddingAnniversary; I could attach more code if necessary).

```
@DayIsBeforeAnniversary
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date weddingDay;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date silverWeddingAnniversary;
    ...
}
```

```
<h:form id="main_form">
    <p:messages />

    <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="id_name" />
    <p:message for="id_name" />
    <p:inputText id="id_name" value="#{personController.person.name}" /><br />

    <p:outputLabel value="Wedding Day" for="id_wedding" />
    <p:message for="id_wedding" />
    <p:calendar id="id_wedding" value="#{personController.person.weddingDay}"  /><br />

    <p:outputLabel value="Silver Wedding Anniversary" for="id_anniversary" />
    <p:message for="id_anniversary" />
    <p:calendar id="id_anniversary" value="#{personController.person.silverWeddingAnniversary}"  /><br/>

    <p:commandButton 
        value="test" 
        action="#{personController.navigate()}" 
        update="@all"/>

    <o:validateBean 
        value="#{personController.person}" 
        showMessageFor="id_wedding id_anniversary" />
</h:form>
```

So my intention is to show the validation message in the `<p:message/>` tags corresponding to the two `<p:calendar/>` tags of which I specified the ID (`showMessageFor="id_wedding id_anniversary"`).

The actual outcome is a bit different. Two messages show up in the general `<p:messages/>` tag. And all input fields are red highlighted (even the input for the name; every input and label has class="ui-state-error"). Actually there is not much difference when I leave out the showMessageFor attribute completely (except there is only one message rendered in the `<p:messages/>`).

[image: Result]

So what am I doing wrong respectivly how can I tell the error messages to appear in the two specific `<p:message/>` tags and how can I prevent the input field for the uninvolved name to become red?

(using Omnifaces 2.6.8 on Glassfish 4.1.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is 2-fold.

1. The `showMessageFor` attribute unintentionally interprets the client ID as the full client ID. Below approach will work for you.

   ```
   <o:validateBean 
       value="#{personController.person}" 
       showMessageFor="main_form:id_wedding main_form:id_anniversary" />
   ```
2. The `showMessageFor` isn't used to mark only specific input fields as invalid. Unfortunately, there is no work around for that other than grabbing [`<o:validateOrder>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOrder) instead.

   ```
   <o:validateOrder
       components="id_wedding id_anniversary"
       message="You cannot celebrate wedding anniversary before being married"
       showMessageFor="@all" />
   ```

Both issues are fixed in 2.6.9 as per [issue 446](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/446).